# How do I change to another view controller

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, viewcontroller

This is probably a stupid question, but as I haven't found an answer anywhere else I will ask it here.

My question is: How can I change which view controller is being viewed. In my case I want the user to open the app, and if the user hasn't already filled out the setup form the app will change from the **home page** to the **setup page**.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    //Initial setup check
    dataBase.SetBool(false, "setUpComplete");

    if (dataBase.BoolForKey("setUpComplete") == false)
    {      
    }
    else
    {            
    }
}
```

Thanks to anyone who decides to answer this!

**EDIT**

My problem is solved as follows. I had to root a navigation controller to the home page and then use the following code below making sure the as a void ViewDidLoad for the other class.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    //Initial setup check
    dataBase.SetBool(false, "setUpComplete");

    if (dataBase.BoolForKey("setUpComplete") == false)
    { 
        SetupViewController screenTwo = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SetupViewController") as SetupViewController;
        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(screenTwo, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would present a viewcontroller in code in Swift 4:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: IdentifierOfTheVC) as? YourVC {
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can set the the Storyboard ID by going to the YourVC's identity inspector and then fill the Storyboard ID field.

Comment: Would you know how to do this is c# as that is the language I am writing in?

Comment: I find that [PresentViewController to a viewcontroller in storyboard](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2983/presentviewcontroller-to-a-viewcontroller-in-storyboard). Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting the first viewcontroller from here, You need to set rootViewController here & push the first page.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    dataBase.SetBool(false, "setUpComplete");
    var rootNavigationController = new UINavigationController(); 
    if (dataBase.BoolForKey("setUpComplete") == false)
    {
       var objSetUpViewController=new LoginViewController()
       rootNavigationController.NavigationController.PushViewController (objSetUpViewController, true);
    }
    else
    {
       var objHomeViewController=new HomeViewController()
       rootNavigationController.NavigationController.PushViewController (objHomeViewController, true);
    }
}
```

From second screen onward you can simply push the pages like

```
 NavigationController.PushViewController(new viewController2(), true);
```

Comment: Where are you defining where SetUpViewController() is? I just get that it doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: `SetUpViewController()`  & `HomeViewController()` is your newly added controllers, you can give any name like ViewController1, LoginViewController etc.. You have to add those. If you didn't added.

Comment: I've added the controllers in a storyboard called Main.storyboard. In the storyboard there are two controllers, one called ViewControllerSetup and ViewControllerMain both in name and storyboard ID. If I use your code  as "var objSetUpViewController=new ViewControllerSetup()" it doesn't work so I i assume I am using is wrong as it is not a class.

Comment: Why you always running after storyboard rather you can add new viewController & push it. When you add ViewController it will come with CS file & UI file.

Comment: I have updated my question with how I solved it. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

(Example for Xamarin.Android) i think u must have a splash page which is the first page, and in the method OnCreate, you have to put the following lines of code:
   (user.SetupExist()--->is a property or method that will return true if the user's settings exist and false if not. )

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
           if(user.SetupExist()){
             var intent=new Intent();
             intent.SetClass(this, typeof(HomePage));
             StartActivity(intent);
           }else
           {
            var intent=new Intent();
             intent.SetClass(this, typeof(SetupPage));
             StartActivity(intent);

           }
```

}

For IOS put this code in ViewDidLoad method:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    if(user.SetupExist())
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new HomePage();
    }else{
     App.Current.MainPage = new SettingPage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that storyboarding on IOS is very different but thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: should look like this:
`if(user.SetupExist())
{App.Current.MainPage = new HomePage();
}else
{
App.Current.MainPage = new SettingPage();
}`